# gcp failure detector with cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am a beginner with google cloud platform, and I am playing with iot-core, pub/sub and could functions. I would like to make a simple failure detector for the devices that send messages to the cloud by pub/sub.

For simplicity, I would like to use directly the telemetries as a heartbeat, but I am having some troubles to put all together.

I sketched this code, which is wrong but I hope can help to understand what I am trying to do.
The idea is to capture the telemetry message and save the corresponding id every time a new one comes. Then, every 10 minutes check if all the previous alive are still there.

```
/* devices on system */
var alive = [1,2];
/* heartbeats */ 
var received = []; 


/**
 * Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event Event payload.
 * @param {!Object} context Metadata for the event.
 */
exports.messagePubSub = (event, context) => {

  // extract device id from message
  const payload = Buffer.from(event.data, 'base64').toString();
  const info = JSON.parse(payload);
  const device = info.id;

  // heartbeat
  if (!received.includes(device){
    received.push(device);
    console.log('${device} is alive');
  }
};


/**
 * Triggered every 10 minutes
 */
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab =
functions.pubsub.schedule('*/10 * * * *').onRun((context) => {
    const topicName = "..."
    
    // find dead devices
    var deads = [];
    for (i = 0; i < alive.length; i++) {
      if (!received.includes(alive[i])){
        deads.push(alive[i]);
        delete alive[i];
      }
    }

    // restore device
    for (i = 0; i < received.length; i++) {
      if (!alive.includes(received[i])){
        alive.push(received[i]);
      }
    }

    // build payload
    const messageObj = {
        data: {
            deads: deads
        }
    };
    const messageBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(messageObj), 'utf8');
    console.log(messageObj);


    // publish failures
    try {
        await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publisher().publish(messageBuffer);
        console.log("Message sent!")
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }

    // reset 
    received = []
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you think about serverless on GCP, think about stateless: your instance can be deleted anytime, and not all the request will land on the same Cloud Functions instance (same thing with Cloud Run and App Engine).

*It's a common mistake, we used to deploy workload on persistent and not ephemeral VM*

So, your problem is you can't rely on your global variables. First, you have 2 functions

- One scheduled every 10 minutes
- One that receive the IoT messages

In any case, it will be never the same instance because it's not the same service (same Cloud Functions). So, the result today should be: all device down, right?

To solve that, you have to persist your data, somewhere.

- Store the data in a database. Firestore or Datastore is a good choice if the number of devices and messages is limited: You have a free tiers of 30k write per day (50k read). If you have a huge number of devices and messages, BigTable will be the recommended solution. In the middle, you can use BigQuery in streaming write.
- Simply logs the device communication.

With the log, as with the database, you simply have to query which devices have sent a message and to compare this with your list of device to detect which ones are dead.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to avoid the overhead of the dataset but I understand my solution was too naive and does not fit serverless solutions. I will deploy 2 separate functions storing the arrays on equivalent database tables then or look for the usage of logs.

Comment: Don't worry, it's a common mistake! Everyone needs to start a day! Don't hesitate to come back if needed!